# jmeter tcp response assertion

Tags: tcp, jmeter, assertion

My device and socket communicate through TCP. Now i want to load test my server so i try to use JMeter.

Server and device keep the connection alive. I will need to send login message before sending any other message. And each message doesn't have any end line character but using some bit to define how long that message is.

Now when i send out my login message, server response with success code. Because the connection is keep, and there no end line character, JMeter doesn't know when will it get full response, so it wait until timeout. I even try Response assertion, using contain word but still not working.

My question is what should i do for this case so when JMeter receive some bit, for example 'SUCCESS' word from server, JMeter will understand that it already pass and keep the connection for next request.